# React Native SVG everywhere, does it make sense?

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-svg

We are considering using `react-native-svg` in our app. We are a bit tempted to use it liberally around the app to create pretty much the visuals of every page, since it should scale better than using images. We are targeting both Android and iOS, tablets and phones.

Does it make sense to make heavy use of SVGs around the app with `react-native-svg` instead of using PNG images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, you should not. I had to deal with svgs a lot of time, and it was always way more complex than pure PNG. If you have to draw icons on tabs or on menus, use PNG, PNG@2x, PNG@3x. `react-native-svg` can be useful for remote SVG loading, like content managed in a back-office.

Comment: Than you for your insights, I appreciate it. Did you mean "remote SVG loading"? What exactly do you mean there?

Comment: You can load content which is not included in your folder `assets/images` for instance. Like a dynamic `drawer` returned by an API call, where every item has a link, and a picture.